# How to capture logout details when user close browser window in oracle Apex User

Tags: oracle, session-cookies, oracle-apex-20.2

How to end user session stored in table when user click on logout url in oracle apex navigation bar and how to end user session when user closes browser window..

Basically I want do load balancing in oracle apex..

Comment: Hi, Stackoverflow works best when you try stuff, it doesn't work, you share the code, and *then* we comment on it.

Answer (score 0):

1. It is not always possible to capture the browser close/tab close event. Even though APEX has a Page Unload Dynamic action it doesn't always work as expected
2. To delete the session on logout you can call an Application Process that deletes the APEX session.

You can use the below code in the Application Process to delete the session.

```
begin
    apex_session.delete_session (
     p_session_id => v('APP_SESSION');
 end;
```